# estuve luchando con este codigo no se que hacer creo que estoy poniendo mal el metodo get si pueden ehcarme una mano les agradeceria

Tags: clase

Esta es la clase using System;

```
namespace classEjercicio1 
{
    class Punto
    {
        private double x, y;
        //public double x, y;
        public Punto (double cx, double cy)
        {
            x = cx;
            y = cy;
        }
        public Punto() : this(0, 0)
        {
        }
        // 1 - crear los metodos get y set para las variables x, y.
       // metodo Get Y set
         public double X
        {
           get { return x;}
           set { x = value; }
        }
         public double Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; } 
        }
        // 2 - Crear el metodo mostrar para imprimir los valores de la variables de instancia
         public void mostrar () 
         {
            Console.WriteLine("valor y --> ");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Dale formato a tu código con `{}` y escribe un título más específico: lee [ask]. ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema?

Comment: Describe mejor tu problema y pon las etiquetas adecuadas, además no te haría mal leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)